# Set MaxDisplayedLines into gridView

Tags: asp.net

I want to set  MaxDisplayedLines to the gidView .
Have you got any idea please ?

Answer (score 0):

you can try with

```
YourGridView.PageSize= yourLimit;
```

And

```
YourGridView.AllowPaging= true;
```

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagrid.allowpaging(v=vs.80).aspx